# Left Join using 3 different tables - django

Tags: python, django

I have to show all articles from a law. Besides that, if the article is setted as marked in database (`is_marked`), I have to underline this article. For that, I need to do a left join, I mean, I have to show all articles, and if the article is marked I need to know that to underline it on the `view`. This marked must be specifc for each user.

my `view`:

```
def details(request, pk):
    law = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=pk)    
    articles = Article.objects.filter(law=pk)

    context = {
        'articles': articles, 
    }
    template_name = 'leis/details.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

My `detail.html`:

```
<div class="article-post"> 
   {% for article in articles %}   
      {{article}}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

That's my `model`:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank = True, null=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField('Artigo/Inciso')
    number = models.IntegerField('Number', blank=True, null=True)
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='articles')
```

This class is saved with  highlights made by a specif user in a specific article in a specif law:

```
class Highlight(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='highlightArticles')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Artigo', related_name='highlightLaw')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='highlightUsers', related_name='highlightUsers')
    is_marked = models.BooleanField('Is it marked?', blank=True, default=False)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank = True, null=True)
```

How can I join the tables to show all the articles, marked with the specif highlights made by an specif user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of Django, you can perform subqueries inside other queries. Assuming you want to underline an article if the current user has highlighted the article, try the following:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

articles = (
    Article
    .objects
    .filter(law=pk)
    .annotate(
        is_marked=Exists(
            Highlight
            .objects
            .filter(
                article_id=OuterRef('id'),
                user=request.user
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This way, we're performing a subquery for every article (don't worry about performance, the database engine will optimize this very well) to check if a Highlight object exists that matches the article and the current user.

Every article in this queryset will now contain an extra boolean member `is_marked` to tell you whether you should highlight it or not.

On a different note, there appear to be some problems with your model definitions. `Highlight.article` is currently a foreigh key to `Law` while I think this should be a foreign key to `Article`.

Comment: Perfect!! Tku so much.